Blender Custom Startup template is causing my high poly mesh to become a circle
I am making a startup file to easily create tillable textures and brush alphas. To do this I create a high poly plane that has x,y tiling enabled in sculpt mode. however when I put the file in the  bl_app_templates_system and load it. the high poly plane becomes a circle that has its points distributed across the circumference. It seems that if I keep the plane below a certain threshold it will still behave as expected.
I don't know if blender has a hidden limit to how much data can be in a startup file or not. it also breaks if  use a sub-div modifier to cross the threshold. Any insight as to why this is behaving like it is would be helpful.

